# Obtaining offline access for Web back-end using GoogleAuthUtil

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get an authorization code for my web back-end using an Android application. According to [cross-client authorization documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth), I should call `GoogleAuthUtil.getAuthToken()` with a scope looking like `oauth2:server:client_id:<back-end client id>:api_scope:resource-1 resource-2`
Here's how I form the scope:

```
private String getOAuthScope() {
    final String scope = "email openid";
    return String.format("oauth2:server:client_id:%s:api_scope:%s",
                         GoogleOAuthData.GOOGLE_OAUTH_SERVER_CLIENT_ID, scope);
```

When I call `GoogleAuthUtil.getAuthToken()`, I get an `INVALID_SCOPE` exception. What is the correct way to form the scope?

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to the question, but ...
whenever you get oauth problems such as this, the best debugging technique I've found is to trace the network requests. You can usually see straight away what the issue is. For Android, this is described here https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/HTTP

Comment: Hey @Ivan Gromov, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown. Any idea why? Is there something wrong with my scopes? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151

Comment: Same GoogleAuthException: Unknown for me.

Answer (score 0):

I initially thought you were using incorrect scope names (e.g "email" rather than "https://mail.google.com/") but according to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login the names are correct for that specific use. However, it looks like the expected scope string is `"openid, email"` not `"email openid"`.

A source of the "Unknown" exception is if your server and client are not part of the same APIs console project.